# How to check speechrecognizer offline recognition packages were downloaded?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I need to know how to check speechrecognizer offline recognition packages were downloaded to determine weather to ask the user to download it. Does anyone know how? Thanks.

Comment: what is the packages name?

Answer (score 0):

I believe offline recognition is only available on jellybean devices.

You can check if the device is running a jellybean.

If it is, try recognizing speech without internet connectivity.

If recognition returned results successfully, it means the offline recognition packages are present on the device. If it doesn't check the kind of error returned and ask users to download the packages